# Array slicing with booleans as indices

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, boolean, slice

Can someone explain this syntax to me?  I've searched through docs/blogs but can't find any mention of using booleans as indices for array slicing.  I found this syntax in this script [`convert_base.py`](http://elementsofprogramminginterviews.com/solutions/python/convert_base.py):

```
is_negative = num_as_string[0] == '-'
num_as_string[is_negative:]
```

My guess is that False is being cast to 0 and True is being cast to 1.  Does anybody know for sure or can point me to any documentation?

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a[True:]
[2,3]
>>> a[False:]
[1,2,3]
>>> a[:False]
[]
>>> a[:True]
[1]
>>> a[False:True]
[1]
>>> a[True:True]
[]
>>> a[False:False]
[]
>>> a[True:False]
[]
>>> a[False::True+1]
[1,3]
```

Comment: It's best not to think in terms of "casting" in Python. While the term is often thrown around loosely, it's pretty meaningless in a very dynamic language like Python where everything is an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the fact that `True` and `False` are subclasses of int which are easily coerced to 1 and 0 respectively, their `__index__` methods used by the Python slice mechanism returns `1` and `0`:

```
>>> True.__index__()
1
>>> False.__index__()
0
```

You can generally slice with arbitrary objects by defining an `__index__` method:

```
>>> class Decade(object):
...    def __index__(self):
...        return 10
... 
>>> range(20)[Decade():] # list(range(...))[Decade():] for Python 3
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: You learn something new everyday. True + True = 2

Comment: Thanks! This explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`True` and `False` are instances of `bool`, a subclass of `int`. `True` has the integer value 1, `False` has the integer value 0.